# Prove f(n) + g(n) is O(max(f(n),g(n)))

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis, notation

Hello I am having a bit of difficulty proving the following.

```
f(n) + g(n) is O(max(f(n),g(n)))
```

This makes logical sense, and by looking at this I can tell you that its correct but I'm having trouble coming up with a proof.

Here is what I have so far:

```
c * (max(f(n),g(n))) > f(n) + g(n) for n > N
```

But I'm not sure how to pick a c and N to fit the definition because I don't know what f(n) and g(n) are.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
f(n) + g(n) <= 2* max{f(n),g(n)} 
(for each n>0, assume f(n),g(n) are none-negative functions)
```

Thus, for `N=1`, for all `n>N`: `f(n) + g(n) <= 2*max{f(n),g(n)}`, and we can say by definition of big O that `f(n) + g(n)` is in `O(max{f(n),g(n)})`

So basically, we use `N=1, c=2` for the formal proof by definition.

Comment: how is c=2 in the above equation?